# How can I import an SQL dump file into a DataSet in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I've got a bunch of SQL dump files that I'd like to import into a dataset with C#. The machine this code will run on does not have SQL installed. Is there any way to do this short of parsing the text manually?

Thanks!

EDIT: The Dump file is just a long list of SQL statements specifying the schema and values of the database.

Comment: How is your SQL dump file like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a SQL dump of the backup sort that you create via a `DUMP` or `BACKUP` statement? If so the answer is pretty much no. It's essentially a snapshot of the physical structure of the database. You need to restore/load the dump/backup to an operable database before you can do anything with it.

Comment: Yes, it's a dump created with the DUMP statement.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was the case, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is no way to turn a bunch of arbitrary SQL statements into an ADO.net DataSet without running the SQL commands through a database engine that understands the SQL in the dump file.  You can't even do it between databases, e.g. a MySQL dump file will not run on an MS SQL server

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to go manual, once you know the format. Creating a DataSet can be done 2 ways:

1. Set up code to loop the file and create a dataset directly
2. Set up code to loop the file and create an XML document in dataset format

Either will work. The best depends on your familiarity with the above (HINT: If you have no familiarity with either, choose the dataset).

It is all a question of format. What type of database is the DUMP file from? MySQL? Postgress? other?

Comment: @Nicholas: You do realize DUMP FILE can mean a lot of things, right?